# Why I couldn't run same installed app on IDE integrated terminal even I could run on default terminal

Tags: bash, ubuntu, intellij-idea, terminal, vscodium

I just switch to try develop on Linux for a while.

But one thing I couldn't understand how to solve it, as I mentioned in topic.

I'm going to develop a project that need Java SDK, then I installed the SDK with command:

```
#bash
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk-headless
```

After installation finished, I could run command `java -version` and `javac -version` to see the result of installation and it looks OK.

```
openjdk version "17.0.3" 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.3+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.3+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And then when I open IDE (Intellij IDEA) and it has feature of integrated terminal. (see picture)

But when I try to test `java -version` it was shown the error:

```
bash: java: command not found
```

As you can see from picture, I run `java -version` on terminal it return output properly, but when I run the same command `java -version`, it output with error message, like it couldn't find the `java SDK` that I installed.

Could anyone help me to describe the reason and solutions to solve the issue?

P.S. This is same on VS Codium.

[image: java command not found on integrated terminal]

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing and what you want. You write about some installed app and produce a screen dump that I cannot match to the question. Please, cut and paste the text instead of posting a picture.

Comment: I added details, hope it could let you know what's issue.

Comment: Do you use the flatpack or the snap version's IntelliJ IDEA? Try to enable the `Shell integration` option under `Settings/Preferences | Tools | Terminal` and restart the IDE.

Comment: If the problem remains please run echo $PATH in the Terminal and the external one and share the output.

Comment: Hi Egor, I'm using Pop OS distributor, and installed it via their Pop!_Shop, and under `shell integration` option was checked as it is from start.
here's the output of echo $PATH `/home/xenogew/.nvm/versions/node/v18.4.0/bin:/home/xenogew/.cargo/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

### Solution:

Install the IDE app with the file from official website instead of using package manager of OS.

### Description:

The cause is I installed the IDE via Package Manager of OS (here I'm using `Pop_OS`, install via `Pop!_Shop`)

And its package manager has some strict rules for security purpose.
I'm not sure, Pop_OS using which package manager, but I'll raise `Flatpak` as reference: https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html

And on blacklisted directories, my installed `java` command is under `/usr/bin/` which is in blacklist.